# No network in slackware

Tags: linux, networking, audio, slackware, kde4

I have just installed Slackware. 
I wonder how to install network in it.

After the Slackware installation, audio and network were not working.

[image: screenshot]

This is how it looks like , no audio , network

Comment: Where specifically are you stuck? The Slackware site has documentation for networking. What did you try? What errors did you get?

Comment: I have updated the question , please take a look

Comment: What you need to tell us is what you've done to attempt to fix this yourself. Did you follow the documentation for networking? What config file did you change, and what was the result?

Comment: as I mentioned , It is just fresh install , I did nothing special to the slackware ,
It was without internet and audio after fresh installation
 If there is any other way to tell you my problem ,please tell me how

Comment: and what I need is to install the internet , I need to run the internet and the audio . That's it

Comment: Slackware's not the right distribution to choose if you expect everything to work out of the box with no customization/configuration. You will need to go read the docs and configure it yourself. When you do that, and if you get stuck, you can come here to get pointers on how to go forward.

Comment: Oh , I get that , I just needed slackware because I heard it is most stable Linux Out there and I want to learn about it

Comment: Given the fact that you describe your unix-like problem with a screenshot, i'd advise to reconsider your choise of distribution. You might want to consider (k)ubuntu, which is a bit friendlier to beginning users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried the instructions on the [official network config site](http://slackware.com/config/network.php)? I think most of your starting configuration questions will be written here.

By the way, if you really want to dive into Linux, don't go for Ubuntu cause you won't ever understand the core workflow of Linux systems. With slackware you will have a hard time learning how to do things, but if you learn something it will stick, go for it!

Comment: I'd agree that Ubuntu moves a lot of traditional Unix/Linux configuration into new GUI-based tools, but then Slackware is hardly a typical Linux.  It has always been closer to FreeBSD in design (from the installer on up) than to the other Linux distributions.

Comment: My Slackware machine is running 12.0, and it works exactly as the official network config site says.

Comment: That is the answer I want , I want to learn more about unix/linux/freebsd. Thank You

Comment: I rarely use any GUI for configuring my kubuntu systems. Then again I learned Linux the hard core way by installing some Gentoo Stage1 systems and then building and maintaining them as my main desktop machine. The good part about Ubuntu'like distributions is that you can start with a fully working system and then build from that. Yes I enjoyed fully building a KDE powered desktop from scratch and I learned a lot from it, but there is little fun in building a for two weeks until you can finally use it the way you want. But it is everybody's free choise,there is no right or wrong.

Answer (score 0):

By default the user account you create isn't in the `netdev` group.

Part of one of the installation guides gives you information on the recommended groups to assign to a user.

https://docs.slackware.com/slackware:beginners_guide#create_a_user_account

> The first thing you will need to do is create your own non-root user
>   account. There are two ways you can do this, both from the console.
>   The recommended way is to use Slackware's own interactive adduser
>   script, thus:
>
> # adduser
>
> and follow the prompts. Read the user management page for more detail
>   on the adduser script. You can use the non-interactive standard Linux
>   program useradd too:
>
> # useradd -m -g users -G wheel,floppy,audio,video,cdrom,plugdev,power,netdev,lp,scanner -s
>   /bin/bash slacker